# Проблема с ссылками на кастомные нугет пакеты после обновления пакетов

Tags: c#, visual-studio, git-merge

Есть набор кастомных нугет пакетов, которые используются в разработке. Они достаточно часто обновляются. После мержа и восстановления пакетов в Visual studio 2019 они отображаются как отсутствующие. Помогает исправить эту ситуацию следующее действие: правой кнопкой на ссылки --> add reference. Возможно ли сделать что-то, чтобы не приходилось выполнять подобные манипуляции?

Comment: Нужно больше информации. Платформа? Где находятся пакеты? Мержа чего? Restore пробовали?

Comment: Windows 10 x64. Пакеты находятся в удаленном репозитории, подтаскиваются нормально, кладутся в папку. После мержа с обновлением пакетов (изменения в пекедж конфиге) при восстановлении пакетов не видит их, пока не будет произведена эта странная манипуляция с "добавить ссылку".

Comment: Попробуйте удалить папку obj вместо "добавить ссылку"

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, попробую!